# How to prove multivariate limits?

Tags: limits, functions, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {\sin(x^2+|xy|)}x $$ I think that the limits tends to zero, i aproach by calculating $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x, 0) = 0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x) = 0$$ but i need to prove it and i'm stuck.

Comment: Observe $|\sin(x^2+|xy|)|\le|x^2+|xy||\le|x^2|+|xy|$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is lot simpler than you think

Assume that x is positive(ie approaches 0 from positive side)

then our equation becomes

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {\sin(x^2+x|y|)}x $$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {\sin(x(x+|y|))}x $$ 
multiply and divide by (x+|y|)

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {(x+|y|)*\sin(x(x+|y|))}{(x+|y|)*x} $$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} (x+|y|) = 0 $$

Similarly when x approaches 0 from negative side

then our equation becomes

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac {\sin(x^2-x|y|)}x $$

Here also answer you get is 0.

So as you approach 0 from any direction, you get 0, you answer is then indeed 0

Comment: Yeah, but the trouble is in the prove by the definition of the limit, i.e., when for every positive epsilon exist a positive delta such that |f(p)-A| < epsilon if |P-R| < delta